# R: How can I change a matrix array?

Tags: r, matrix, sequence, bioinformatics

I have a matrix, like:

```
"aaa" 28
"aac" 8
"aag" 20
```

I want to replace "aaa" with "K", "aac" with "N" and "aag" with "K". How can I do this using R?

Comment: @ agstudy: I defined the first column as a vector, and then use $ to replace, but I didn't work.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your new example (aag -> G); if you can give some context about the bioinformatic goal, it maybe that the `Biostrings` package can do it easily ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many options here. Unfortunately you don't show any effort to resolve the problem or even to make it clear and reproducible. For example, using `ifelse` :

```
dat <- read.table(text='"aaa" 28
                  "aac" 8
                  "aag" 20')
dat$V1 <- with(dat,ifelse(V1 %in% c('aaa','aag'),'K','N'))
dat
  V1 V2
1  K 28
2  N  8
3  K 20
```

**EDIT**
 If I want to replace "aaa" with "K", "aac" with "N" and "aag" with "G":

```
dat$V1 <- with(dat,ifelse(V1 == 'aaa',
                          'K',
                          ifelse(V1=='aac','N','G')))
 dat
  V1 V2
1  K 28
2  N  8
3  G 20
```

Comment: @ agstudy: I tried to ask my question briefly. If I want to replace "aaa" with "K", "aac" with "N" and "aag" with "G", how I should change the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closer to what you're trying to do:

```
 ## if necessary, install the package first:
 ##  source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
 ##  biocLite("Biostrings")
 library(Biostrings)
 d <- data.frame(string=c("aaa","aac","aag"),count=c(28,8,20))
 tfun <- function(x) as.character(translate(DNAString(x)))
 transform(d,aa=sapply(string,tfun))
 ##   string count aa
 ## 1    aaa    28  K
 ## 2    aac     8  N
 ## 3    aag    20  K
```

If you prefer you can use

```
 transform(d,string=sapply(string,tfun))
```

to do the replacement in place.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: You're  right but I want to do this without any bioC packages.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: It's part of my project